# unable to fetch the list values from the website

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-shell

i fetch all the detail from the desire website but unable to get the some specific information please guide me for that.

> targeted domain: https://shop.adidas.ae/en/messi-16-3-indoor-boots/BA9855.html
>
> my code is`response.xpath('//ul[@class="product-size"]//li/text()').extract()`

[image]

> need to fetch data!!!

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: It is loading from javascript.

Comment: @mkHun please can you give me **guide lines** to accomplish the task. thanks

Comment: In view page source  check for following JS variable `window.assets.sizesMap`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Often ecommerce websites have data in json format in page source and then have javscript unpack it on users end.

In this case you can open up the page source with javascript disabled and search for keywords (like specific size).

I found in this case it can be found with regular expressions:

```
import re
import json
data = re.findall('window.assets.sizesMap = (\{.+?\});', response.body_as_unicode())
json.loads(data[0])
Out: 
{'16': {'uk': '0k', 'us': '0.5'},
 '17': {'uk': '1k', 'us': '1'},
 '18': {'uk': '2k', 'us': '2.5'},
 ...}
```

Edit: More accurately you probably want to get different part of the json but nevertheless the answer is more or less the same:

```
data = re.findall('window.assets.sizes = (\{(?:.|\n)+?\});', response.body_as_unicode())
json.loads(data[0].replace("'", '"')) # replace single quotes to doubles
```

Comment: i am getting an error while applying your code.  
`IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-3a8177c66705> in <module>()
      1 data = re.findall('window.assets.sizes = (\{.+?\});', response.body_as_unicode())
----> 2 json.loads(data[0].replace("'", '"'))

IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Seems like your regular expression is different. Mine is `'window.assets.sizes = (\{(?:.|\n)+?\});'` vs your's `'window.assets.sizes = (\{.+?\});'`.

Comment: sir @Granitosaurus can you help me out for splash, how i will install on my machine to accomplish this task.i tried but could not accomplish it.

Comment: @MuhammadZiaUrRahman You should open up a new question describing what issues you are facing with your splash installation. I'm not sure splash even supports windows platform as there are no install instructions for it in the [docs](http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html). Either way as my example showed splash is unnecessary in your case.

Comment: sir in your way how i can i get the only 'eu' values from the object. please guide me thanks

Answer (score 1):

The data you want to fetch is loaded from a javascript. It is said explicitly in the tag `class="js-size-value "`.

If you want to get it, you will need to use a rendering service. I suggest you use [Splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash), it is simple to install and simple to use. You will need **docker** to install splash.

Comment: While it's a great lazy option it's far from being neccessary. You can replicated javascript with python in scrapy by digging around a bit.

Comment: Yes I agree. I'll dig more before using splash everywhere.Thanks for the tip :-)

Comment: @Blanquer Adrien means possible it can be possible with scrapy to get the javascript base data.

Comment: @BLANQUERAdrien please can you give me splash code example to get the data. i am trying but could not get the result. thanks

Comment: @BLANQUERAdrien Docker is not running on my machine Windows10 please can you help me out to accomplish this task sir. thanks

Comment: @Muhammad Zia Ur Rahman Sorry for the delay, you should install `docker` following this [tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/) if you are working on windows. Once you installed docker check the [splash documentation](http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#installation) and install it. Let me know :-)

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. i install the docker tool box and further i am unable to run it. please guide me further thanks

Comment: I'm afraid it will be complicated to debug your docker installation here, I suggest you make another post for this particular problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146029/discussion-between-muhammad-zia-ur-rahman-and-blanquer-adrien).